# Microsoft SQL Server, error:18452

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Cannot attach an exit database.
I have created a database in another computer with SQL Server, but now it cannot be attached in SQL Server.

Comment: What **versions** of SQL Server do you have ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dhite/archive/2007/12/23/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-login-failed-error-18452.aspx)

Check the above link which may help you to fix it

Comment: The link is dead